# installing gem from a github fork

Tags: git, rubygems, gemfile, git-fork, mongify

I have installed a `mongify` gem from original source:
https://github.com/anlek/mongify

then I want to install a newer version from a fork (has not been accepted yet for pull by original source, but it has an update that i need),

link to the fork:
https://github.com/yuvalkarmi/mongify

what should I do to update `mongify` in my device from the fork (not from the original source)?

Thanks

Comment: like currently in my system i have installed mongify using: gem install mongify
then it works fine with a local instance of MongoDB, and with a remote MongoDB instance hosted in https://mlab.com/. however, it does not work with a MongoDB cluster hosted by MongoDB Atlas, since the latter supports only MongoDB 3.4 , and SSL is enabled. the version forked by yuvalkarmi provides support for SSL and MongoDB 3.4.
now, having this in mind, what should i do exactly to update my current version of mongify so that it works as exactly as modified by @yuvalkarmi

Answer (score 11):

Just set the source as the url to the fork.
There are quite a few ways to do this:

If you are using bundler:

```
gem 'mongify', :git => 'https://github.com/yuvalkarmi/mongify'
```

Or:

```
gem install mongify -s https://github.com/yuvalkarmi/mongify
```